# What does "I Solisti Veneti" mean?

Tags: terminology, history, classical-music, baroque-period

- What does Vivaldi mean by "I Solisti Veneti"?
- What does the title mean?

There doesn't seem to be a translation I could find of.

Comment: Not really certain this is on topic here...

Comment: A quick search in the Wiktionary seems to indicate it simply means “The Soloists from [Veneto][https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Veneto]”.

Comment: While this is a well-known ensemble busily playing and recording Vivaldi, I'm not aware of Vivaldi himself using that term - do you have a source?

Comment: No, sorry @guidot.

Comment: @guidot there's a contemporary musical ensamble called "[I Solisti Veneti](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/I_Solisti_Veneti)", and they play period music. I suppose the score, the youtube video title or whatever the source of this sentence is referencing to the arrangement of this piece used by them, rather than something Vivaldi himself put in writing.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to my Italian colleague it means (as Édouard commented):

> The (=I) soloists (=solisti, regular  [but somewhat unexpected, since one has to know, that the gender of the word is male] plural from solista) from
>   Veneto (i. e. the region, from which Venice is the capital).

Comment: good translation - I'll get rid of my attempt, which I guess was close but no cigar.

Comment: Why “irregular plural”? All derived substantives in -ista (which works for both males and females) naturally go -isti (or -iste when feminine), e.g. il/la violinista - i violinisti / le violiniste, l’apprendista - gli apprendisti / le apprendiste...

Comment: @giobrach: Your examples as well as the sparse profile data let me assume, that Italian is you mother tongue.  Is my edit more correct?

Comment: Yes, that’s better!